# Declare Variable with dash(hyphen) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables

I want to declare a variable in swift which contains dash in its name

for eg:  `var store-types-categories = JSON()`

I am getting error as `Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`

Please let me know how to use the same name, should i use some escape sequence or what is the best solution?

Thanks

Comment: Use underscores...

Comment: sorry can't use... dash is needed

Comment: Don't use dashes or underscores; dashes are not valid in Swift variable names and under scores are icky :). camelCase is accepted style for Swift.  If you need to match a key in your JSON for `Codable` using a `CodingKeys` enumeration.

Comment: Read points https://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/DataBasics/naming.htm

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID412 lists which characters are allowed in a variable name – the dash (hyphen) is not among them.

Comment: @MoinShirazi Almost all languages don't let you use "minus" as component of variable identifier. Swift is very flexible and you can use many things as letters (all Unicode letters); but dash and alike are not letters. So you may find something that looks like "dash" and considered as letter in Unicode and use it, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

Swift treats the `-` as a unary operator known as `subtraction`. It is impossible to use `-` in any other way. As suggested in some of the comments, your best options are

1) Underscores: `my_tacos`

2) camelCase: `myTacos`